# What is the behaviour of arcDistance script field filter with a multi valued field geo_point?

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the behaviour of the script filter:

```
doc['distance'] >= doc['locations'].arcDistance(lat, lon)
```

If locations is a multi valued field of type geo_point?

I would like for it to match if any of the locations meet the criteria. From experimentation I think it matches the first point.

When you return the distance:

```
doc['locations'].arcDistance(lat, lon)
```

Which point will it pick? The first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to look this up in the source code. It only uses the first location.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me. ES has in it's [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/sort/) that it should be possible to select the closest (minimum) value as well. I cant get this to work however. Did you happen to play with this and get it to work?

Comment: I ended up writing a custom script in java to achieve that exact scenario https://gist.github.com/cyberdemon/72e11751f481caae195e. It's not pretty... I didn't see anything in the documentation at the time about it, it would have really helped!